# Brownie: Unable to launch local RPC client

Tags: brownie

I was trying to run brownie for ganachi-cli, but it keeps giving me this error. My node is up to date and I have changed my host in the ganachi-cli UI. What do I do?

```
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Ethproject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 44, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "brownie/network/main.py", line 50, in connect
    rpc.launch(active["cmd"], **active["cmd_settings"])
  File "brownie/network/rpc/__init__.py", line 93, in launch
    raise RPCProcessError(cmd, uri)
RPCProcessError: Unable to launch local RPC client.
Command: ganache-cli
URI: http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

Comment: I am running WSL2.

Comment: yeah, does not work for me either

Answer (score 2):

if it still doesn't work after installing version `16.13.2`, then make sure you run this extra command after installing:

```
nvm use 16.13.2
```

After you run this `nvm use` command, try rerunning your script.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually the node version, you just need to downgrade the node.

`nvm uninstall <current version>`

`nvm install 16.13.2`

Comment: still does not for me, but it partly work after running ganache from a separate terminal

Answer (score 0):

make sure you provide your WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID for brownie, when I added WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID to my .env file, this  problem has been solved.

brownie uses it:
[image]

and make sure to tell brownie that you are using .env file in brownie-config.yaml:
[image]

.env file:
[image]